# Hibernate cascade vs Separate calls

Tags: java, hibernate

Lets say I Have two entities with a one to one relationship, a person entity and a person detail entity. Are there any advantages to using cascade when I want to save as oppose to making a separate save for each entity?

Would it be different if it was not a one to one relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, one difference would be, if NOT cascade, there will be multiple network calls (N+1 effect). Based on size data, there are lot of other implications you need to worry about too.

Comment: would multiple network calls still be made if it were warped around a transaction ?